# restrict bootstrap visible-md to it's container size

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a page with two column layout which by default second column is collapsed and first columns has col-xs-12 class. by clicking on a button both columns get col-xs-6 class. at this time I want to hide some things because of limited space. If I use visible-md on a div it'll be hidden when the size smaller than 992px. Here is the problem, the window size hasn't changed though the container size is changed ( from col-xs-12 to col-xs-6). Is there away to restrict visible-md functionality according it's container size not browser window size? I mean without writting jquery. using bootstrap's classes.
Thanks

Comment: I doubt that this is possible using Bootstrap’s default functionality. You are probably better off writing a small CSS rule that hides the element based on certain viewport widths yourself.

Comment: OK then, It's better writing a piece of jquery code

Comment: Why? Why would using jQuery be better than letting CSS do the job it is supposed to do?

Comment: if you mean using @media ( max-width: 992px){} it works like bootstrap. it depends on window size not container size

Comment: But the container width depends on the window width as well, no? (If not, then you would basically be asking for what people call “element queries”, which don’t exist yet, but there’s some script out there that help achieve the effect.)

Comment: could you make a sample code for me, or at least describe what you mean by css rule?

Comment: You want to hide stuff that is inside one of those columns? Well then just used the descendant selector or similar to only select those elements when the column has the class … `.col-xs-6 .something { display:none; }`

Comment: the container is using col-xs-12 which is dependent on window size. I want  to hide some elements when class switches to col-xs-6

Comment: yeah .col-xs-6 .something { display:none; } will work. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt that this is possible using Bootstrap’s default functionality. You are probably better off writing a small CSS rule that hides the element <del>based on certain viewport widths</del> yourself.

If you want to hide stuff that is inside one of those columns when the column(s) have that class – then you could just use the descendant selector or similar to only select those elements when the column has the class …

```
.col-xs-6 .something { display:none; }
```

(This does of course not have any relation to specific viewport widths any more – but since you are toggling the class dynamically, that should not matter in this instance.)

Answer (score 0):

As @cBroe said, Have you tried using .hidden-md a default class on the elements that you wanted to hide? This works in bootstrap v3.